Cannot get ResponseEntity of specific Class type in Spring Integration Test
I have a ITest in Spring which looks like this:
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class AuthControllerITest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate template;

    @Test
    public void shouldGetAccessToken() throws Exception {
        String email = "a@a.pl";
        String url = AuthController.GET_TOKEN_PATH+"?email="+email;

        ResponseEntity<AuthResponse> response = template.getForEntity(url, AuthResponse.class);

        assertThat(response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful());
    }
}

But method execution causes an error
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class com.my.app.security.ui.response.AuthResponse] and content type [application/json]

AuthResponseController action and Response model look like following:
@GetMapping(AuthController.GET_TOKEN_PATH)
public ResponseEntity<AuthResponse> auth(@RequestParam(required = false) String email)
{
    if (null == email) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Email must be provided");
    }

    User user = userRepository.findUserByEmail(email);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthResponse(jwtService.createToken(user)));
}

public class AuthResponse {
    private String token = "some token";

    public AuthResponse(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }
}

It works when I switch type from specific class to just a String:
ResponseEntity<String> response = template.getForEntity(url, String.class);

But I want to get AuthResponse object - besides the status code I want to check if generated token is correct.
So could you tell me why I cannot get the mapped AuthResponse object?

Change the method's signature and your return value:
@GetMapping(AuthController.GET_TOKEN_PATH)
public AuthResponse auth(@RequestParam(required = false) String email)
{
  ...
  return new AuthResponse(jwtService.createToken(user));
}

Edit
It turned out that the reason for this exception are a missing constructor and setter in AuthResponse:
public class AuthResponse
{
   public AuthResponse()
   {
   }
   ...
   public void setToken(String token)
   {
      this.token = token;
   }

Another option is to use, as I usually do, a record instead of a class:
public record AuthResponse(String token)
{
}


Thank you for helping me but unfortunately after changing the code I still got the same exception org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class com.my.app.security.ui.response.AuthResponse] and content type [application/json] when I'm running the test

Did you call the method remotely when running your application? What's the result?

One other thing: Instead of first making the email non required (required = false) and then checking if its provided you should go with required = true and omit the additional check.

Got idea with that required=true :) When I call endpoint via Postman I got nice json response 200 OK {"token": "..."}.

Thank you very much for solving that problem :) You were right with that missing setter - I've removed constructor and applied @Data annotation and I can easily get mapped response object in my Integration Test. You're awesome!
